# Show that $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(X),P)$ is a closed hilbert subspace of $L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{A},P)$ s.th $\sigma(X) \subset \mathbb{A}$

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces

I was self-studying probability theory(conditional expectation). I know that a subspace is $U$ of $V$ is a set $U \subset V$ s.th $\forall x,y \in U$ and $\forall \alpha, \beta \in F$ we have that $\alpha x+\beta y \in U$. But 
I am a bit confused here because the sigma algebra getting coarser( $\sigma(X) \subset \mathbb{A}$) makes $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(X),P) \subset L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{A},P)$. I mean we say that a $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{A},P) \implies E^P[X^2] < \infty $ and similarly $X \in L^2(\Omega, \sigma(X),P) \implies E^P[X^2] < \infty$ How does the change in the sigma algebra makes the latter the subspace of the former. It is clear to me why the set square integrable r.v's forms a hilbert space . But I cant think of an $x \in L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{A},P) $ which does not belong to $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(X),P)$ 
Sorry if its a stupid question but I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to go.  Choose a sequence $\{Y_n\}$ with 
$Y_n\to Y$ in $\mathcal{L}^2$.  You can pass to a subsequence so that 
$Y_n \to Y$ almost everywhere. This tells you that $Y$ is measurable in any $\sigma$-algebra for which the $Y_n$ are measurable.

Comment: I don't follow why this argument answers my question. Could you please explain a little more? Thanks

Comment: I thought a little bit more about it. So if I choose a r.v $Y$ s.th  $\mathbb{A}=\sigma(Y)$ then ofcourse choosing a  $Y \in L^2(\Omega,\sigma(Y),P)$ but if we fix a r.v $X$ s.th $\sigma(Y) \supset \sigma(X)$ strictly then $Y \notin L^2(\Omega,\sigma(X),P)$ as Y would not be $\sigma(X)$ measurable. Does this make sense?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Let me reformulate your question a little bit. We want to show that if $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{F_0}$ is a subsigma-algebra, then $L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F_0},\mathbb{P})$. As you have argued, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a proper subsigma algebra of $\mathcal{F_0}$, then also $L^{2}(\mathcal{F})$ is a proper subspace of $L^{2}(\mathcal{F_0})$. And you are right, this is not because of integrability, since the integrals are the same, but measurability: (Take $A\in\mathcal{F_0}$ s.t $A\notin\mathcal{F}$ and consider $1_{A}$).

The above answer proves that $L^2(\mathcal{F})$ is closed in $L^{2}(\mathcal{F_0})$.